# Starting navigation controller from appDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller

Can anyone tell me how to start `UINavigationContoller` from ÀppDelegate`?
I can start a`rootViewContoller`but cannot start a specific`UIViewController`like I was trying in commented code.
The commented code starts the **ChooseTableViewController** but does not display`UINavigationBar`.
whats the better approach?
Here is my code

```
- (void)setRootViewController:(NSString *)storyBoardName {
    //set the Root ViewController

    UIStoryboard *story = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyBoardName 
                                                    bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *newViewController = 
                                 [story instantiateInitialViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = newViewController;



    /*
    ChooseTableViewController *chooseTableViewController = 
      [story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChooseTableViewController"];

    self.window.rootViewController = chooseTableViewController;

    */

}
```

Comment: Putting `ChooseTableViewController` as the rootViewController of the `UINavigationController` will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Appdelegate.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController;
```

Appdelegate.m

```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{

     self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];

            UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

       self.navigationController  = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navigation"];
              UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChooseTableViewController"];
              navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController];
     self.window.rootViewController =self.navigationController;
            [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;
    }
```

Comment: what is    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navigation"  here?? its is crashing on that line

Comment: it means the navigation controller will be your initial view controller and the identifier of the navigation controller is @"navigation"

Comment: but it is crashing there

Comment: do yo have any navigation controller on storyboard?

Comment: self.navigationController  = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController]; try this instead of   self.navigationController  = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navigation"];

Comment: thank you @ahmed .Its is working, but navigation bar is not displayed properly, and yes i am using Navigation controller which is linked to ChooseTableViewController. anything could be done over this?

Comment: did you set your top bar in the view controller?

Comment: how you want to display and how it is displayed?

Comment: its is custom navigation drawer and its property is not getting applied in ChooseTableViewController

Answer (score 0):

```
// Your main storyboard
UIStoryboard *story = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyBoardName bundle:nil];

// Your root navigation controller
UINavigationController *newViewController = [story instantiateInitialViewController];

// Your root view controller for root navigation controller
ChooseTableViewController *chooseTableViewController = [story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChooseTableViewController"];

// Set your view controller as root view controller of your root navigation controller
newViewController.rootViewController = chooseTableViewController;

// set your root navigation controller
self.window.rootViewController = newViewController;
```